# jQuery scroll() detect when user stops scrolling

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, jquery-events

Ok with this..

```
$(window).scroll(function()
{
    $('.slides_layover').removeClass('showing_layover');
    $('#slides_effect').show();
});
```

I can tell when someone is scrolling from what I understand. So with that I am trying to figure out how to catch when someone has stopped. From the above example you can see I am removing a class from a set of elements while the scrolling is occurring. However, I want to put that class back on when the user stops scrolling.

The reason for this is I am intent on having a layover show while the page is scrolling to give the page a special effect I am attempting to work on. But the one class I am trying to remove while scrolling conflicts with that effect as its a transparency effect to some nature.

Comment: possible duplicate of [fire event after scrollling scrollbars or mousewheel javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8931605/fire-event-after-scrollling-scrollbars-or-mousewheel-javascript)

Comment: Awesome, not exactly duplicate but definitively up the alley of what I was looking for and helped me in the end solve my issue. Thank you.

Answer (score 267, accepted):

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    clearTimeout($.data(this, 'scrollTimer'));
    $.data(this, 'scrollTimer', setTimeout(function() {
        // do something
        console.log("Haven't scrolled in 250ms!");
    }, 250));
});
```

**Update**

I wrote an *extension* to enhance jQuery's default `on`-event-handler. It attaches an event handler function for one or more events to the selected elements and calls the handler function if the event was not triggered for a given interval. This is useful if you want to fire a callback only after a delay, like the resize event, or such.

It is important to check the github-repo for updates!

**https://github.com/yckart/jquery.unevent.js**

```
;(function ($) {
    var on = $.fn.on, timer;
    $.fn.on = function () {
        var args = Array.apply(null, arguments);
        var last = args[args.length - 1];

        if (isNaN(last) || (last === 1 && args.pop())) return on.apply(this, args);

        var delay = args.pop();
        var fn = args.pop();

        args.push(function () {
            var self = this, params = arguments;
            clearTimeout(timer);
            timer = setTimeout(function () {
                fn.apply(self, params);
            }, delay);
        });

        return on.apply(this, args);
    };
}(this.jQuery || this.Zepto));
```

Use it like any other `on` or `bind`-event handler, except that you can pass an extra parameter as a last:

```
$(window).on('scroll', function(e) {
    console.log(e.type + '-event was 250ms not triggered');
}, 250);
```

http://yckart.github.com/jquery.unevent.js/

(this demo uses `resize` instead of `scroll`, but who cares?!)

Comment: It's still not 100% accurate: sometimes user stops and resumes scrolling even after 250 ms

Comment: This code works great, but it broke jquery ui's autocomplete widget totally.

Comment: @ArmanBimatov then it will be considered as the user keeps scrolling, which sounds good, no?

Comment: This timeout only fires when scroll events stops and NOT when the user stops scrolling. The user can lift their finger from the mouse and scrolling can continue for a few seconds depending on the speed of their scrolling. This solution will not give you an indication when the user has stopped scrolling.

Comment: @yckart thanks for your work. but a thing... setTimouts breaks context binding. so inside handler function there is no access to the context... I couldn't find any workaround for that. Can you edit it to support that?

Comment: @abzarak this abstract helper isn't perfect, in no case! I haven't updated the github-repo recently, for reasons — this was an terrible idea. Just use a "throttle" or "debounce" wrapper function instead. I should note that somewhere else too! :)

Answer (score 54):

## Using jQuery throttle / debounce

[jQuery debounce](http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-throttle-debounce-plugin/) is a nice one for problems like this. [jsFidlle](http://jsfiddle.net/hYsRh/4/)

```
$(window).scroll($.debounce( 250, true, function(){
    $('#scrollMsg').html('SCROLLING!');
}));
$(window).scroll($.debounce( 250, function(){
    $('#scrollMsg').html('DONE!');
}));
```

The second parameter is the "at_begin" flag. Here I've shown how to execute code both at "scroll start" and "scroll finish".

## Using Lodash

As suggested by Barry P, [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/barrypeterson/zzghqk62/), [underscore](http://underscorejs.org/) or [lodash](https://lodash.com/) also have a debounce, each with slightly different apis.

```
$(window).scroll(_.debounce(function(){
    $('#scrollMsg').html('SCROLLING!');
}, 150, { 'leading': true, 'trailing': false }));

$(window).scroll(_.debounce(function(){
    $('#scrollMsg').html('STOPPED!');
}, 150));
```

Comment: Is it possible to utilise a normal scroll function at the same time?

$(window).scroll(function(){ ... });

Comment: Of course, jQuery will bind as many handlers to an event as you'd like.

Comment: Thanks for updating this @BarryP Jsfiddle also provides lo-dash so you can avoid the external link http://jsfiddle.net/qjggnyhf/

Comment: FYI, I was having issues where rapid scrolls were not reverting back.  It seemed that you needed to add a few milliseconds to the "STOPPED" debounce, else it causes a race condition where, sometime, the STOPPED triggers before the STARTED, and you end up with the item stuck as if you are still scrolling.  I made mine 150 and 160, respectively, and it seemed to do the trick.

Comment: Thanks @CodeChimp that's neat, but I'd worried about handling edge cases by fixing them 15 out of 16 times ;) Maybe a single handler with all of the logic inside would be safest. Check the `leading` and `trailing` yourself, then be sure that there can be no confusion.

Comment: @Sinetheta, you are absolutely right.  One method to rule them all would not only be cleaner, but it seems safer.

Comment: ➕100 if it was possible.

Answer (score 10):

Rob W suggected I check out another post here on stack that was essentially a similar post to my original one. Which reading through that I found a link to a site:

http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/special-scroll-events-for-jquery/

This actually ended up helping solve my problem very nicely after a little tweaking for my own needs, but over all helped get a lot of the guff out of the way and saved me about 4 hours of figuring it out on my own.

Seeing as this post seems to have some merit, I figured I would come back and provide the code found originally on the link mentioned, just in case the author ever decided to go a different direction with the site and ended up taking down the link.

```
(function(){

    var special = jQuery.event.special,
        uid1 = 'D' + (+new Date()),
        uid2 = 'D' + (+new Date() + 1);

    special.scrollstart = {
        setup: function() {

            var timer,
                handler =  function(evt) {

                    var _self = this,
                        _args = arguments;

                    if (timer) {
                        clearTimeout(timer);
                    } else {
                        evt.type = 'scrollstart';
                        jQuery.event.handle.apply(_self, _args);
                    }

                    timer = setTimeout( function(){
                        timer = null;
                    }, special.scrollstop.latency);

                };

            jQuery(this).bind('scroll', handler).data(uid1, handler);

        },
        teardown: function(){
            jQuery(this).unbind( 'scroll', jQuery(this).data(uid1) );
        }
    };

    special.scrollstop = {
        latency: 300,
        setup: function() {

            var timer,
                    handler = function(evt) {

                    var _self = this,
                        _args = arguments;

                    if (timer) {
                        clearTimeout(timer);
                    }

                    timer = setTimeout( function(){

                        timer = null;
                        evt.type = 'scrollstop';
                        jQuery.event.handle.apply(_self, _args);

                    }, special.scrollstop.latency);

                };

            jQuery(this).bind('scroll', handler).data(uid2, handler);

        },
        teardown: function() {
            jQuery(this).unbind( 'scroll', jQuery(this).data(uid2) );
        }
    };

})();
```

Answer (score 5):

I agreed with some of the comments above that listening for a timeout wasn't accurate enough as that will trigger when you stop moving the scroll bar for long enough instead of when you stop scrolling. I think a better solution is to listen for the user letting go of the mouse (mouseup) as soon as they start scrolling:

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
    $('#scrollMsg').html('SCROLLING!');
    var stopListener = $(window).mouseup(function(){ // listen to mouse up
        $('#scrollMsg').html('STOPPED SCROLLING!');
        stopListner(); // Stop listening to mouse up after heard for the first time 
    });
});
```

and an example of it working can be seen in [this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TheoI/gFJwG/1/)

Comment: This seems great, but if you are scrolling by 2-finger gesture on a trackpad, or a scrollwheel, then the mouseup isn't fired.  This is probably the most common way to scroll too, which makes it problematic.

Comment: Good point. But potentially there are a couple of fixes for that. Using jquery's 'mousewheel' event or keeping track on if mousedown first, and using a timeout approach as suggested by others. But I think using a combination of other answers for mouse wheel events and this answer for scroll bar dragging will give the most accurate results

Answer (score 5):

ES6 style with checking scrolling start also.

```
function onScrollHandler(params: {
  onStart: () => void,
  onStop: () => void,
  timeout: number
}) {
  const {onStart, onStop, timeout = 200} = params
  let timer = null

  return (event) => {
    if (timer) {
      clearTimeout(timer)
    } else {
      onStart && onStart(event)
    }
    timer = setTimeout(() => {
      timer = null
      onStop && onStop(event)
    }, timeout)
  }
}
```

Usage:

```
yourScrollableElement.addEventListener('scroll', onScrollHandler({
  onStart: (event) => {
    console.log('Scrolling has started')
  },
  onStop: (event) => {
    console.log('Scrolling has stopped')
  },
  timeout: 123 // Remove to use default value
}))
```

Answer (score 3):

You could set an interval that runs every 500 ms or so, along the lines of the following:

```
var curOffset, oldOffset;
oldOffset = $(window).scrollTop();
var $el = $('.slides_layover'); // cache jquery ref
setInterval(function() {
  curOffset = $(window).scrollTop();
  if(curOffset != oldOffset) {
    // they're scrolling, remove your class here if it exists
    if($el.hasClass('showing_layover')) $el.removeClass('showing_layover');
  } else {
    // they've stopped, add the class if it doesn't exist
    if(!$el.hasClass('showing_layover')) $el.addClass('showing_layover');
  }
  oldOffset = curOffset;
}, 500);
```

I haven't tested this code, but the principle should work.

Answer (score 3):

```
function scrolled() {
    //do by scroll start
    $(this).off('scroll')[0].setTimeout(function(){
        //do by scroll end
        $(this).on('scroll',scrolled);
    }, 500)
}
$(window).on('scroll',scrolled);
```

very small Version with start and end ability

Answer (score 2):

This detects the scroll stop after 1 milisecond (or change it) using a global timer:

```
var scrollTimer;

$(window).on("scroll",function(){
    clearTimeout(scrollTimer);
    //Do  what you want whilst scrolling
    scrollTimer=setTimeout(function(){afterScroll()},1);
})

function afterScroll(){
    //I catched scroll stop.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok this is something that I've used before.
Basically you look a hold a ref to the last `scrollTop()`. 
Once your timeout clears, you check the current `scrollTop()` and if they are the same, you are done scrolling.

```
$(window).scroll((e) ->
  clearTimeout(scrollTimer)
  $('header').addClass('hidden')

  scrollTimer = setTimeout((() ->
    if $(this).scrollTop() is currentScrollTop
      $('header').removeClass('hidden') 
  ), animationDuration)

  currentScrollTop = $(this).scrollTop()
)
```

Answer (score 0):

please check the [jquery mobile scrollstop event](http://www.w3schools.com/jquerymobile/event_scrollstop.asp)

```
$(document).on("scrollstop",function(){
  alert("Stopped scrolling!");
});
```

Comment: thats jquery mobile, not jquery. i almost fell for the same trap ;)

Answer (score 0):

For those Who Still Need This Here Is The Solution

```js
  $(function(){
      var t;
      document.addEventListener('scroll',function(e){
          clearTimeout(t);
          checkScroll();
      });
      
      function checkScroll(){
          t = setTimeout(function(){
             alert('Done Scrolling');
          },500); /* You can increase or reduse timer */
      }
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
var Timer;
$('.Scroll_Table_Div').on("scroll",function() 
{
    // do somethings

    clearTimeout(Timer);
    Timer = setTimeout(function()
    {
        console.log('scrolling is stop');
    },50);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can handle this:

```js
    var scrollStop = function (callback) {
        if (!callback || typeof callback !== 'function') return;
        var isScrolling;
        window.addEventListener('scroll', function (event) {
            window.clearTimeout(isScrolling);
            isScrolling = setTimeout(function() {
                callback();
            }, 66);
        }, false);
    };
    scrollStop(function () {
        console.log('Scrolling has stopped.');
    });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>
</body>
</html>
```