# How can I make a fix positioned menu bar?

Tags: css, css-position, fixed, menubar

I would like to style my menu bar [Like THIS](http://happycog.com/). 
It's fixed to the top of the site when you scroll down and it isn't fixed where it is when the page is loaded.

How can it be done with CSS?

Comment: please add some code or a jsfiddle link

Comment: possible duplicate of [Creating a sticky nav css and jquery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11538428/creating-a-sticky-nav-css-and-jquery)

Comment: FWIW, the linked site no longer uses this style of menu bar. This is why vishnu suggested adding code to this post.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What you're after is a 'sticky navbar/menu'.

The simplest way would be to add the below CSS to your menu/navbar

```
position:fixed;
top:0px;
```

That said, for an effect closer to the one you've posted, you'll probably want to look at using some jQuery, e.g.:

```
$(window).bind('scroll', function() {
     if ($(window).scrollTop() > 50) {
         $('.menu').addClass('fixed');
     }
     else {
         $('.menu').removeClass('fixed');
     }
});
```

What this does is 'fix' the menu bar to the top of the page once you scroll past a certain point (e.g. 50px) by adding the CSS class 'fixed' to the `.menu` element, the fixed class would simply be e.g. the CSS above.

There are some nice examples listed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11538428/creating-a-sticky-nav-css-and-jquery).

Answer (score 2):

**Source:** [Creating a sticky nav css and jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11538428/creating-a-sticky-nav-css-and-jquery)

**HTML**

```
<div id="menu">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Shop</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div id="content">
This is some content 0<br/>
This is some content 1<br/>
This is some content 2<br/>
This is some content 3<br/>
This is some content 4<br/>
This is some content 5<br/>
This is some content 6<br/>
This is some content 7<br/>
This is some content 8<br/>
<div id="data" />
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
* {
    font-family: Consolas,Sans-serif;
    font-size: 10pt;
}
#menu {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
}
#menu.out {
    position: fixed;
}
#menu ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 1em .5em;
    list-style: none;
    background-color: #fc9;
}
#menu ul li {
    display: inline-block;
}
#menu ul li a {
    padding: 5px .5em;
}
#content {
    background-color: #ebebee;           
    padding: 4em 1em 1em;
    height: 900px;
}
```

**JQuery:**

```
    var menu = $("#menu");
var ul = menu.find("ul");
var content = $("#content")[0];
var data = $("#data");
var menuHeight = menu[0].getBoundingClientRect().bottom;
var inView= true;

$(document).scroll(function(evt) {
    evt.preventDefault();
    var top = content.getBoundingClientRect().top;
    var nextInView = top+menuHeight > 0;

    if (inView ^ nextInView)
    {
        data.append("<div>Switching.</div>")
        inView = nextInView;
        if (inView)
        {
            menu.removeClass("out");
        }
        else
        {
            menu.addClass("out");
            ul.hide().slideDown("fast");
        }
    }
});
```

Fiddle :[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/dMLX7/)

Courtesy : [***Robert Koritnik***](https://stackoverflow.com/users/75642/robert-koritnik)

Hope this helps

Happy Coding