# How to load comments only when posts reach the center of the window with jquery

Tags: jquery, load, scroll

I'm trying to create the same "animation" as seen there:

http://letmehaveblog.blogspot.it/?view=classic

Comments of a post are loaded only when the post reach the center of the window. My code works fine if I only change the css display or opacity properties of the div that contains the comments (the height of the posts isn't modified) but becomes a mess when I use slideUp/slideToggle as I want to simulate the load of a php script through ajax. I'm dealing with this javascript code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
var winWidth, winHeight;

function show_post_content() {

/* Check the location of each desired element */                          
$('.post').each( function(i){    

var top_of_object = $(this).position().top;       
var top_of_window = $(window).scrollTop();                                                                
var bottom_of_object = $(this).position().top + $(this).outerHeight();
var bottom_of_window = $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height();          

/* If the object is completely visible in the window, fade it in */   
//if( bottom_of_window > bottom_of_object ){  
if( top_of_object < parseInt(winHeight / 2)) {                            

    //$(this).children('.comments').css('display','block');                                                                      
    //$(this).children('.comments').animate({'opacity':'1'},500);  
    //$(this).children('.comments').fadeIn(500);  
    //$(this).children('.comments').animate({'opacity':'1'},500);
    $(this).children('.comments').slideToggle('slow');   

}                                                                     

});      

}    

function hide_post_content() {

  $('.post').each( function(i){

    $(this).children('.comments').slideUp();

  });   

}    

function init() {
  winWidth = $(window).width();
  winHeight = $(window).height();

  hide_post_content();
  show_post_content();  
}

init();

$(window).resize(function () {
  init();
});

/* Every time the window is scrolled ... */
$(window).scroll( function(){       
  show_post_content();      
});     

});
```

The HTML is that one:

```
<div class="post">Post  
<div class="comments">Comments</div>
</div>
<div class="post">Post  
<div class="comments">Comments</div>
</div>
<div class="post">Post  
<div class="comments">Comments</div>
</div>
...
```

With css:
    .post {
      opacity: 1;
      width: 600px; 
      min-height: 100px;
      background-color: #ffffff;
      display: block;
      padding:0px;
      margin: 30px auto;
      border: 1px solid #000000;
    }

```
.comments{
  opacity: 1;
  width: 580px;
  height: 50px;
  display: none;
  margin:100px 0 0 0; 
  padding:10px; 
  background-color: #aaaaaa;    
}
```

I've searched for an answer here but can't find the one which could put me on the right path. Any idea or advice? Thank you very much, Eric

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `slideToggle` function does its animation asynchronously. It also changes the position of the later post elements. So in the `each` function you are calling `slideToggle` and then moving on to the next iteration before `slideToggle` is done changing the position of your other post elements. That's one issue. Another is that the scroll event is going to fire a bunch of times when you scroll. More times than it's necessary to execute `show_post_content`.

So here are some suggestions:

1. As a first step, make sure `show_post_content` works the way you want, regardless of the scroll event. You should pull `show_post_content` out of the `ready` function (you'll have to add `winHeight = $(window).height();` to the beginning). Then you'll be able to execute it from the console in Chrome or Firefox. Do that after you scroll to different positions on the page and make sure it works the way you expect. You may want to change your function to stop after one post is done or go on to the next one only after the animation is finished (`slideToggle` allows you to pass a callback function for when it's done).
2. Throttle the `scroll` event. There's [this](http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-throttle-debounce-plugin/) plugin or you can search around SO for other options. Even better would be to only run `show_post_content` when the user stops scrolling. That's harder, but you can start [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9144560/jquery-scroll-detect-when-user-stops-scrolling).