# Fix <div> to top until it reaches the end of it's container

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have the following code:

```
<div class="span4" style="height:1000px;">
 <div id="iphone-frame">
  <div id="iphone">
   <div id="iframe-iphone">
    <h1><div id="titlePreview"></div></h1>
    <h2><div id="subtitlePreview"></div></h2>
    <p><div id="contentPreview"></div></p>
   </div>
  </div>
  <div id="iphone-shadow"></div>
</div>
```

What I am trying to do it write some Javascript so that `<div id="iphone-frame">` fixes to the top of the window when it is scrolled past, until it gets the the end of it's container (`<div id="span4">`)

What I have tried:

- Modifying this: http://jsfiddle.net/trepmal/e7GN8/
- The jquery.scrollfollow.js plugin

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 2):

I've created a fiddle as well (took note of your comment on Vector's answer) here: http://jsfiddle.net/asifrc/XLKmH/

I added the class `sticker` to the div you want to stick and changed the `div` selector in the css to `sticker` accordingly. The cloning business at the beginning of your code was redundant so i got rid of it.

I then added the following line that calculate's `sticker`'s bottom:

```
var bottom = $('.sticker').parent().offset().top + $('.sticker').parent().height();
```

and then changed the if statement from `if (dist >= fromtop)` to

```
if (dist >= fromtop && dist <=  bottom)
```

I then deleted the .hide() line as it was also redundant (to me, might've been useful to you somehow).

Let me know if this is what you were looking for, and if you have any questions :)

Comment: FYI, `<div class="span4"> ends near "They're like sex, except I'm having them! "

Answer (score 0):

try this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hsex3/). It uses window scrolling stop detection from [jQuery scroll() detect when user stops scrolling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9144560/jquery-scroll-detect-when-user-stops-scrolling). And scrolls an element up/down based on `$(window).scrollTop()`