# where to put jquery codes in blogger

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, blogger

i got the correct codes which could solved my problem, in previously posted questions  : [How do I get an image to fade in and out on a scroll using jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17928132/how-do-i-get-an-image-to-fade-in-and-out-on-a-scroll-using-jquery)

```
var divs = $('.banner');
$(window).scroll(function(){
if($(window).scrollTop()<10){
  divs.stop(true, true).fadeIn(5000);
} else {
   divs.stop(true, true).fadeOut(5000);}
});
```

now I can't understand how to implement this code in blogger.

Comment: First: What's your problem? Second: Where's the question?

Comment: i want to make a div hidden, when scrolled upto a certain point say 500px from top, after crossing that point it could become visible again.

Comment: this is link, where i found the answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17928132/how-do-i-get-an-image-to-fade-in-and-out-on-a-scroll-using-jquery

Answer (score 4):

First include the jQuery in your `<head>` if you don't have it (this is compulsory, else you won't be able to use any jQuery code).

```
<script src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.23/jquery-ui.min.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
```

Then paste this code in your `<body>` between the `<script>` tag

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var divs = $('.banner');
$(window).scroll(function(){
if($(window).scrollTop()<10){
  divs.stop(true, true).fadeIn(5000);
} else {
   divs.stop(true, true).fadeOut(5000);}
});  
</script>
```

Comment: Glad to know its working.Please check the correct answer.