# Make a div(s) disappear when a user starts scrolling and make it appear when the user stops scrolling

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've seen the iOS 7 video and they've created this awesome effect in their Safari browser. When a user starts scrolling, all the menus and option slide away and when a user stops scrolling, the menus and options slide back and become visible.

How can I create a similar effect with JQuery. Let's say I've got two divs which contain options and settings, when a user starts scrolling, they slide away and when the user stops scrolling, they slide back and become visible.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The javascript `scroll` event i believe is fired when the users *starts* scrolling. I would do something like the following:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
     // user started scrolling, hide div.
     clearTimeout($.data(this, 'scrollTimer'));
     $.data(this, 'scrollTimer', setTimeout(function() {
        // user paused scrolling for 250ms, show div.
        console.log("Haven't scrolled in 250ms!");
     }, 250));
});
```

This is just adapted from [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14092859/1149459).