# Adjust scroll position to a closest div

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-scrollable

Here i have bunch of div's with some related contents.

I want to adjust the scroll position to a closest div

[Example Website](http://www.takumitaniguchi.com/tokyoblue/)

[Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/naresh_k28/Yd4SH/3/)

How can i do this using jQuery

**JQuery**

```
$(".item").scroll( function( ) {
    $(".item").css({ top: $(this).scrollTop( ) });
});
```

Could anyone help me,

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: you can do this by `window.location.hash = 'your div id';`

Comment: @ABFORCE buti want i t dynamically every time i scroll

Comment: you can set `hash` property every time you need

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here you go. You have to do a couple of things.

- listen when the scrolling stops
- find the "*next*" container
- scroll to its top value, without triggering "the scroll end detection"

**JavaScript**

```
var items = $(".item");
var animating = false;

$(window).scroll(function() {
    clearTimeout($.data(this, 'scrollTimer'));
    if (!animating) {
        $.data(this, 'scrollTimer', setTimeout(function() {
            items.each(function(key, value) {
                if ($(value).offset().top > $(window).scrollTop()) {
                    animating = true;
                    $('body').animate( { scrollTop: $(value).offset().top + 'px' }, 250);
                    setTimeout(function() { animating = false; }, 300);
                    return false;
                }
            });
        }, 200));
    }
});
```

The "scroll end detection" is coming from [yckart's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1250044/yckart) to [jQuery scroll() detect when user stops scrolling](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14092859/1456376). All timings from this example can be adjusted to your needs.

**Demo**

[Try before buy](http://jsfiddle.net/kZY9R/)

Comment: it is only scrolling down to Top, but i want both(TOP / BOTTOM) based on which div is closest

Comment: I'm not on a computer currently, but I think you can easily adjust it to your needs yourself from here.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
window.location.hash = 'your div id';
```

your updated fiddle : [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Yd4SH/6/)

**UPDATE**
if you want to do this in a smooth way try this:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    var winScroll = $(this).scrollTop(); // current scroll of window

    // find cloest div
    var cloest = $('your main divs').first(); // first section
    var min = 10000;
    $('your main divs').each(function() {
        var divTopSpace = $(this).offset().top - winScroll;
        if( divTopSpave < min && divTopSpave > 0 ) {
            cloest = $(this);
            min = divTopSpace;
        } 
    });

    // animate
    $(document.body).animate({scrollTop: cloest.offset().top}, 'slow');
});
```

Comment: i don't want to trigger with any button, it should happen dynamically, when i scrolls up/down

Comment: @NareshKamireddy put this statement in `onscroll` listener

Answer (score 0):

### Working Sample **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/sarathsprakash/Yd4SH/7/)**

Try this

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var full_url = this.href,

        target_offset = $('.item:first').offset(),
        target_top = target_offset.top;

    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: target_top
    }, 500);
});
```

Comment: i want it for every div, not only for first div

Answer (score 0):

I thing you look for this..

[check demo](http://jsfiddle.net/A2she/2/)

```
<div class="item" id="123">(123 div Here )pi ali waso sewi sijelo, li suwi anpa kalama ale. ike n prep sama sijelo, monsi nanpa sitelen mi ike. lipu kute telo ko ijo, e ali taso poki. ken ko sike nanpa. ike o luka suli. unpa kiwen uta a.pi ali waso sewi sijelo, li suwi anpa kalama ale. ike n prep sama sijelo, monsi nanpa sitelen mi ike. lipu kute telo ko ijo, e ali taso poki. ken ko sike nanpa. ike o luka suli. unpa kiwen uta a.</div>

<div style="width:20%;float:right;position:fixed;right:0px;">
   <ul>
       <li><a href="#123">123</a></li>
       <li><a href="#456">456</a></li>
       <li><a href="#789">789</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: i don't want to trigger it with any hash/button, means while scrolling it should happen

Comment: Interesting alternative to lorem ipsum. I don't see it used anywhere else, did you write the toki pona text custom for this answer?

Answer (score 0):

To get it to work in Firefox, use

```
$('body,html').animate( ... );
```

Answer (score 0):

I found solution for what you want to achieve. You can change 200 on the following line so height from and to the top of the box will change.

```
if ($(window).scrollTop() < $(value).offset().top+200 && $(window).scrollTop() > $(value).offset().top-200 )
```

full code

```
var items = $(".thebox");
var animating = false;
    $(window).scroll(function() {
        clearTimeout($.data(this, 'scrollTimer'));
        if (!animating) {
            $.data(this, 'scrollTimer', setTimeout(function() {
                items.each(function(key, value) {
                    if ($(window).scrollTop() < $(value).offset().top+200 && $(window).scrollTop() > $(value).offset().top-200 ) {
                        animating = true;
                        $('body').animate( { scrollTop: $(value).offset().top + 'px' }, 250);
                        setTimeout(function() { animating = false; }, 300);
                        return false;
                    }
                });
            }, 200));
        }
    });
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/Yd4SH/13/)

Answer (score 0):

Following method will help to adjust Div scroll position so that selected inner Div is viewable in view port.

**jQuery :**

```
function adjScrollPosition(container, elem) {
var h = container[0].clientHeight;
var w = container[0].clientWidth;
var t = container.scrollTop();
var l = container.scrollLeft();
var b = t + h;
var r = l + w;
elem = elem[0];
var eh = elem.offsetHeight;
var ew = elem.offsetWidth;
var et = elem.offsetTop;
var el = elem.offsetLeft;
var eb = et + eh;
var er = el + ew;
var top = et < t || eh > h ? et : b < eb ? t + (eb - b) : t;
var left = el < l || ew > w ? el : r < er ? l + (er - r) : l;
// If you want to bring element in center of the view port uncomment following lines
//var top = et - (h / 2) + eh;
//var left = el - (w / 2) + ew / 2;

$(container).stop().animate({ scrollTop: top, scrollLeft: left }, 500);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
                if ($(".text-danger").length) {

                    $(document).ready(function () {
                        $('html, body').animate({
                            scrollTop: $("form#partner-register-form div.text-danger").first().offset().top - 60
                        }, 1000);
                    });
                }
```

Comment: I was feeling the same case so I find the shortest and perfect solution.