# After Mouse wheeler happened

Tags: jquery, gallery, mousewheel

I'm using jquery mouse wheeler function in my gallery.

this is my function

```
function galleryFirst() {
$(".gallery-slider ul li:first-child").addClass("selected");
$(".gallery-slider ul li").mousewheel(function() {
    $(".gallery-slider ul li").removeClass("selected");
    $(".gallery-slider ul li:first-child").addClass("selected");
});
}
```

I want to add class after the mouse wheeler complete. can any one help on this please...:)

Comment: What do you mean with "complete"? Each tick is a single event (do you want to group more events together?)

Comment: i mean that class adding should be happened after scrolling finish. i just wanted to add a class to the first element after scrolling finish.

Comment: I hope this discussion help you a lot
 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9144560/jquery-scroll-detect-when-user-stops-scrolling