# How to write a script that fades an element in for a while when user is scrolling, and fades it some time after user stopped scrolling?

Tags: jquery, html, scroll, fadein, fadeout

Here's my codepen example: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/zgvrH

It works on Chrome and Safari, but on IE10 and FireFox it sometimes gets stuck looping the fade in and fade-out for a long time. 
Gif of the problem: https://i.stack.imgur.com/zIDt3.gif

How should I edit the script to make it work in all browsers?

Another question (not as important): is it possible to make the h2 so that the user could click a link that's below it? Fade-in-out -thingy is a request from a client and I'm just trying to make it as pleasant for the users as possible.

I'm using jQuery.

Thank you very much!

Comment: Good you provided the codepen link but you should add your code in the question also

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9144560/jquery-scroll-detect-when-user-stops-scrolling