# JQuery if else on scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i want to change CSS or menu bar while scrolling and restore old CSS when scroll stops  using if else.
this is what i did so far.

```
if ($(window).scroll(function () {
    $('#nav').css('opacity', '0.85');
} else {
    $('#nav').css('opacity', '1');
});
```

working code without if statement

```
$(document).scroll(function() {
    $('#nav').css('opacity', '0.85');
});
```

Comment: any fiddles to show?

Comment: `if ($(window).scroll` is... very strange. What really do want to check in `if`?

Comment: That if, and the braces, are completely out of whack.

Comment: `$(window).scroll()` binds a handler to the scroll event. It doesn't return anything that you can test with `if`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery scroll() detect when user stops scrolling](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9144560/jquery-scroll-detect-when-user-stops-scrolling)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Scroll and scrollstop

```
$(document).on("scroll", function() {
  $('#nav').css('opacity', '0.85');
});

$(document).on("scrollstop",function(){
  $('#nav').css('opacity', '1');
});
```

Comment: can you give the fiddle for the same

Comment: Sorry The above method is available in jquery mobile. But you can use the link mentioned in comment.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
 scrolling = "Scrolling",
 stopped = "Stopped";

        $( window ).scroll(function() {
            console.log(scrolling);
            clearTimeout( $.data( this, "scrollCheck" ) );
            $.data( this, "scrollCheck", setTimeout(function() {
                console.log( stopped );
            }, 250) );

        });
```