# Show <div> when entering into that div alone

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, asp.net

I need a help in j query. I want to show 4 div elements(div1, div2, div3, div4) only when I scroll the scroll bar in the browser. How can I do that? Please help.

Comment: Check jquery [.scroll()](http://api.jquery.com/scroll/) function combining with [.show()](http://api.jquery.com/show/).

Answer (score 0):

check out this links :

[jQuery scroll() detect when user stops scrolling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9144560/jquery-scroll-detect-when-user-stops-scrolling)

http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/special-scroll-events-for-jquery/

http://james.padolsey.com/demos/scrollevents/

EDIT : and this one

```
[jsfiddle sample][1]
```