# Disabling event when scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to disable temporaly event `mouseup` when user scroll the div. I test bind scroll event on div and `preventDefault` and `stopImmadiatePropagation` on event but not work.

Prototype of code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(document).on("mouseup", "#test", function(e) {
      $("body").append('<b style="color:red">Mouse up | </b>');
  });
  $("#test").scroll(function(e) {
      $("body").append('<b style="color:green">Scroll | </b>');
      e.preventDefault();
      e.stopImmediatePropagation();
  });
});
```

I provide this plunker example: [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/E2fqT9dzZ5lHTiTp7fkS?p=preview)

Comment: Please add code here and not just links. Read this carefully: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: you can add `($document).off("mouseup", "#test")` inside the callback for scroll event  if you just want to disable it

Comment: Not work, and I think the `.off` disable completly my `mouseup` event, test in plunker!

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/a/14092859/5317080

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use `.off()`

[JQuery API documentaion](http://api.jquery.com/off/)

**Update:**

The right solution: [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/IMscpJoT6btU3zTMkrbk?p=preview)

Comment: Not work, and I think the `.off` disable completly my `mouseup` event, test in plunker!

Comment: Perhaps this solution will help: http://plnkr.co/edit/IMscpJoT6btU3zTMkrbk?p=preview

Comment: It's maybe a trick using timeout with delay? Is the only one solution?

Comment: Yes, I think, because we need only turn off the event immediately after the scroll.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(document).on("mouseup", "#test", function(e) {
      $("body").append('<b style="color:red">Mouse up | </b>');
  });
  var isScrolling = false;
  $("#test").scroll(function(e) {
      $("body").append('<b style="color:green">Scroll | </b>');
      e.preventDefault();
      e.stopImmediatePropagation();
      isScrolling = true;
      setTimeout(function(){
        isScrolling = false;
        setTimeout(function(){
          if(!isScrolling){
            $(document).off("mouseup", "#test");
            $(document).on("mouseup", "#test", function(e) {
              $("body").append('<b style="color:red">Mouse up | </b>');
            });
          }
        }, 500);
      }, 500);
      $(document).off("mouseup", "#test");
  });
});
```

It will disable the `mouseup` event when the scroll event is fired.

http://plnkr.co/edit/630M9zZpNxXGBABvPq8q?p=preview