# Accurately Capture the 'scrollend' event on Mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, cordova, hammer.js

When using the `-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;` style on a mobile element, capturing the `scroll` events can be extremely tiresome as they are triggered by 'flicking', 'panning' and when the scroll itself stops.

Unlike desktop browsers, this makes it a nightmare to try to detect when either, the element is currently being scrolled, or, the element has finished scrolling.

I have researched around SO and the web a hell of a lot and have ascertained that the only viable solution (that I can think of) is to create a function that captures the first touch of the scroll, ignores any subsequent `pan`'s and then captures the final scroll event.

If this could be accomplished, somehow, then an incremented value could represent `scrollend` whenever it is even...

I have written the following but I have ommitted the `touch` events as I do not really know where to start with this part:

```
var checklist_scroll = 0; // Whenever this value is even, it means the scroll has ended
$('ul').on('scroll',function(){
    checklist_scroll++; // Only do this for 'scrollstart' and 'scrollend', NOT when panning through the list
});
```

Then, for any other event, you could do

```
$('li').on('tap',function(){
    // Only make the elements selectable when parent is not scrolling
    if(checklist_scroll%2===0){
        // Select the li
    }
});
```

Comment: scrollstart, stop events are only provided with jquery mobile. with jquery you have only scroll. if you want to detect a scroll start, stop you need to add a library -- https://github.com/ssorallen/jquery-scrollstop -- check here also for a possible scroll solution -- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9144560/jquery-scroll-detect-when-user-stops-scrolling

Comment: @Tasos Please can you post up the link to scrollstop in an answer as I was able to solve my issue using it. Once you have posted the answer, I can edit it with the code and then accept it as the answer to give you the credit :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [jquery-scrollstop](https://github.com/ssorallen/jquery-scrollstop) plugin to add scroll start/stop detection functionally.

See this example:

```
var scrolling = false;
$('#some_element').on('scrollstart',function(){
    scrolling = true;
});
$('#some_element').on('scrollstop',function(){
    scrolling = false;
});

$('#some_tappable_element').hammer().on('tap pressup',function(){
    // Use a timeout to ensure the scrolling var has been updated
    setTimeout(function(){
        if(!scrolling){
            // Select the element
        }
    },10);
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this! The events don't fire quite as you would expect them to, but they work well enough to provide a viable solution to the issue.

Comment: @Ben Carey -- looks ok. i assume you have a timing issue -- have you tried using the (setTimeout(function(){ .. ) inside the (scrollstop) function instead of the (tap)?

Comment: Its not really a timing issue, I would actually expect it. Because the `tap` event and the `scrollstop` event are fired at the same time, the `scrolling` var has been set by the time the `tap` function executes, so it has to delay a little bit in order to catch the correct value. I could probably get away by setting the timeout value to 1 but I wanted to be sure and as it doesnt make any different to the user, it should be okay

Comment: @Ben Carey -- ok, it works as expected -- keep in mind that hammer js has settings and might be able to tune the threshold limit, when i used hammer i played around with these and they do make a difference -- http://hammerjs.github.io/recognizer-tap/