# jquery off('scroll') not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

we are trying to implement simple hiding menu when scroll, and showing back when user stops scrolling, but `.on('scroll')` works but `.off('scroll')` doesn't

```
$(document).on('scroll',hideMenu);
$(document).off('scroll',showMenu)
function hideMenu(){
     $('#home_menu').fadeOut();
}
function showMenu(){
     $('#home_menu').fadeIn();
}
```

what is happening?
when we start scrolling menu fades away, but when we stop scrolling, it doesn't fade it

Comment: Did you try to read the jQuery API documentation?

Comment: [`jQuery.off`](http://api.jquery.com/off#entry-longdesc) is used to remove a handler, so that it wont be call anymore for that event.

Comment: 'on' addEventListener, and 'off' delete it

Comment: Check this question [jQuery scroll() detect when user stops scrolling](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9144560/jquery-scroll-detect-when-user-stops-scrolling)

Comment: Read the accepted solution [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9144560/jquery-scroll-detect-when-user-stops-scrolling)

Comment: @t.niese I was 4 seconds too late :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a `setTimeout` instead, that will be canceled (*cleared*) each time there is a scroll, and when the scroll stops, make it execute `showMenu` :

```js
var menuTimer;
$(window).on("scroll", hideMenu);

function hideMenu()
{
    clearTimeout(menuTimer);
    $('#home_menu').fadeOut();
    menuTimer = setTimeout(showMenu, 900);
}

function showMenu()
{
    $('#home_menu').fadeIn();
}
```

```css
body{padding-top:3em;font-family:Arial,Helverica,sans-serif}
#home_menu{position:fixed;top:0;left:0;width:100%;padding:1em;background:#1b83db;color:#fff}
p{margin-bottom:3em}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="home_menu">Menu</div>

<p>Some text</p><p>Some text</p><p>Some text</p><p>Some text</p><p>Some text</p><p>Some text</p><p>Some text</p><p>Some text</p><p>Some text</p><p>Some text</p><p>Some text</p><p>Some text</p><p>Some text</p><p>Some text</p><p>Some text</p><p>Some text</p><p>Some text</p><p>Some text</p><p>Some text</p><p>Some text</p><p>Some text</p><p>Some text</p>
```

Comment: that was some precise answer, i would loved the native version(i guess it doesn't exists) but if it's working i've no problem :)

Comment: @runningmark Sorry for the delay, but what do you mean by "native version"? Without jQuery? Or the equivalent of what you wanted `.off('scroll')` to do?

Comment: i apologies for not being clear, with native i meant without using intervals :)

Answer (score 0):

There is a misunderstanding here:

`.off("scroll")` does **not** mean that a callback has to be invoked when the **scroll** ends.

Instead it **detach** the callback from the `scroll` event.

What you want is invoke a callback when the scroll starts, invoke another one when it stops.

There are many ways to accomplish this.

This is my approach (the code is self-explaining):

```
$(document).on('scroll',scrollStart);

// A scroll has started

function scrollStart()
{
    var lastScrollY;

    // record the position

    lastScrollY = $(window).scrollTop();

    // hide the menu

    hideMenu();

    // detach the event. We don't want the callback called again for now.

    $(document).off('scroll',scrollStart);

    // let the function scrollRunning be called after 1 sec

    setTimeout( function() { scrollRunning( lastScrollY ) }, 1000 );
}

// A scroll is going on. Or maybe has ended

function scrollRunning( lastScrollY )
{
    var currentScrollY;

    // current scroll position

    currentScrollY = $(window).scrollTop();

    // did the position change ? Scroll is going on
    // schedule scrollRunning to check again after 1 sec

    if( lastScrollY != currentScrollY ) // Scrolling is going on
    {
        lastScrollY = currentScrollY;
        setTimeout( function() { scrollRunning( lastScrollY ) }, 1000 );
    }
    else // Scrolling has stopped. Show the menu and reattach the event
    {
        $(document).on('scroll',scrollStart);
        showMenu();
    }
}
```