# ON/OFF css class in javascript - for animation handling

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation

I would like to know how to implement java script that allows me to add a css class to an element when i scroll and to remove it when i stop scrolling. on/off situation

Comment: Your question is a little bit too general. What would be the primary goal of your implementation? Fastest or easiest to implement? Best performance? Portability? Though honestly, all of the above would be solved by jQuery, as long as you're not developing for mobile.

Comment: Have you tried searching for libraries such as [ScrollMagic](http://scrollmagic.io)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery scroll() detect when user stops scrolling](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9144560/jquery-scroll-detect-when-user-stops-scrolling)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it like this:

```
$(window).on('scroll', function() {
  $('#someID').addClass('red');
});

$(window).scroll(function() {
  clearTimeout($.data(this, 'scrollTimer'));
  $.data(this, 'scrollTimer', setTimeout(function() {
    $('#someID').removeClass('red');
  }, 250));
});
```

Class `.red` just adds red color for testing.

You can test it here https://jsfiddle.net/byxpsnwu/

I used [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9144560/jquery-scroll-detect-when-user-stops-scrolling) SO answer.

Comment: How does one do this for multiple elements ..

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/XynDigital/c738hw43/   is the animation set of items im tryna animate on scroll and stop other wise..