# Scroll divs like slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll

Sorry if the title sound confusing, but i'm not good at english so i don't know how to phrase my though better.

I have few divs, each div i make full `width` and `height` of the browser's window. When user scroll down (or up), it will scroll to the next (or previous) div like a [vertical slider](https://www.jssor.com/demos/vertical-slider.slider). It somewhat sound similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12849439/treating-each-div-as-a-page-when-scrolling), but since i don't know much about javascript or jquery, i'm not sure how to adapt the accepted answer to my work. So far i only able to create the html and css similar to my work. Something like this.

```css
html, body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 100%;
}
div {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
.div-1 {
    background-color: lightblue;
}
.div-2 {
    background-color: green;
}
.div-3 {
    background-color: silver;
}
```

```html
<div class="div-1"></div>
<div class="div-2"></div>
<div class="div-3"></div>
```

Comment: You might get some ideas from this http://stackoverflow.com/a/39188110/3377049

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use verticle background slider then the best option is to use the fullPage.js script to slide your background on the scroll.

Just download the required JS and CSS file and use `vertical-scrolling` class inside your div which you want to slide on the scroll.

Please follow [this](https://webdesign.tutsplus.com/articles/vertical-and-horizontal-scrolling-with-fullpagejs--cms-24215) link to know more about this and you can see demo [here](http://codepen.io/tutsplus/full/VvZXMP/).

I hope this will helpful for you.

Thanks.

Comment: Nice, exactly what i'm looking for. Thank you so much!