# javascript Bootstrap Progressbar fill in 10 seconds

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a Progressbar in Bootstrap that fills every 1 sec 10% of the progressbar.

The problem is, that the site lags over the whole browser (chrome), but why?

That's my code that fills the Progressbar

```
var isPaused = false;
$(window).scroll(function(){
    var ScrollTop = parseInt($(window).scrollTop());
    if (ScrollTop > 10) {
        isPaused = true;
    } else {
        isPaused = false;
    }
});


var timeleft = 1;
var table_updated = 0;
var timeleft_zahl = 10;
var tick = function() {
    if(!isPaused && $("#page-1").hasClass("active") && !$(".modal").hasClass("show")) {
        document.getElementById("progressBar").style.width = timeleft*10+"%";
        document.getElementById("refreshcountdown").innerHTML = timeleft_zahl-1;
        timeleft += 1;
        timeleft_zahl -= 1;
        if(timeleft >= 11){
            notificationcheck();
            timeleft = 0;
            timeleft_zahl = 11;
            if(table_updated >= 10) {
                location.reload();
                table_updated = 0;
            } else {
                get_table_data(1);
                table_updated += 1;
            }
        }
    }
}

timer = setInterval(tick, 1000);
```

So it's just simple.
I have a few options, like `isPaused` and some other things that stops the progressbar filling, cause when user scroll, than it must stop.

But why does it lag? the Interval runs every 1000 (so 1 sec) to fill every 1 sec 10% if isPaused false and the other if things are correct

Answer (score 0):

Your `tick` function is called every second, thus only every second there is a decision whether to increase the progress bar or not.

I guess the "lags" you discover are just imaginary because your scrolling will never take an exact amount of seconds like 1, 3 or 5 seconds but something like 1.4 or 3.8 seconds. Thus, you think the increase of your progress bar is delayed because it takes some milliseconds until the `tick` function is called again.

To avoid this effect you could add a listener that fires when no scrolling is performed (in other words, when the scroll stops). In that case you should reset the `setInterval` function.

Comment: Did you have an example (code) for me please? If a user is on the site and doesnt scroll, the interval runs cause every 1 sec the progressbar must go 10% more...

Comment: [This StackOverflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9144560/jquery-scroll-detect-when-user-stops-scrolling) provides solutions how you can track if the user stops scrolling. In that case, just call `clearInterval(timer);`.

Comment: i dont understand the main problem what you mean... Cause if i kick the hole scroll thing out of my code, its also lagging... Its lagging cause the interval calls every 1 sec i think, but i need that to update progressbar :/