# @keyframe animation on scroll event

Tags: javascript, jquery, css-animations, keyframe, onscroll

I'm using a variable font and would like to animate it using @keyframes on scroll and then not animate when the user stops scrolling.

I can make the animation work, however when you stop scrolling, the animation stops and snaps back to the starting position which makes it look very jumpy.

To make it more of a smooth finish, I'm wondering if there is a way that when the user stops scrolling, it is possible to get the current position of the animation and then complete that animation loop and then stop, instead of snapping immediately back to the starting position?

As i cannot load the variable font into a jsfiddle using @font-face, i've put it up here:
http://slug.directory/GX/

Here is the js...

```
    $(document).ready(function() {

    var scrollTimerId;

    $(window).scroll(function() {
        if (!scrollTimerId)
            $('body').addClass('scrolling');

        clearTimeout(scrollTimerId);
        scrollTimerId = setTimeout(function(){
            $('body').removeClass('scrolling');
            scrollTimerId = undefined;
        },150);
    });
});
```

and css...

```
@keyframes changewidth {
  0% {
    font-variation-settings: 'wght' 1;
  }

  100% {
    font-variation-settings: 'wght' 100;
  }
}

.scrolling {
  animation-duration: 0.5s;
  animation-name: changewidth;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-direction: alternate;
 animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

body {
    font-family: "AG GX", Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
    font-size: 2vw;
    line-height: 2vw;
    font-variation-settings: 'wght' 1;
    height: 300vh;
}

div {
  position: fixed;
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: *I'm using a variable font and would like to animate it using @keyframes on scroll and then not animate when the user stops scrolling.* Animate it how? *I can make the animation work*. I opened the link and it's not animating when I'm scrolling.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The situation you are facing is simply how to transition from any point in an animation to a static position.
There is unfortunately no CSS defined way, so we have to resort on javascript to handle that.

The basic idea is to trigger that transition manually. `getComputedStyle` can give you the value at which your animation currently is, so we can set it on our element's inline style, and then remove it right after a forced reflow for the transition to the original position triggers.

Unfortunately Safari behaves weirdly and we have to toggle the transition property too, making this operation force 3 synchronous reflows...

Here is an example using a moving box, as its easier to set up as a snippet:

```js
const box = document.getElementById( 'box' );
onclick = e => {
  box.style.setProperty( 'transform', getComputedStyle( box ).transform );
  // set the inline style to the current value
  box.classList.toggle( 'anim' ); // disable the animation
  
  box.offsetWidth; // trigger a first reflow just for Safari
  box.classList.toggle( 'transition' ); // toggle the transition
  box.offsetWidth; // trigger an other reflow so the browser knows where we are
  box.style.removeProperty( 'transform' ); // come back to initial position
};
```

```css
#box {
  width: 50px; 
  height: 50px;
  background: lime;
}
.anim {
  animation: move 2.5s infinite;
}
.transition {
  transition: transform 2s;
}
@keyframes move {
  from { transform: translate(0, 0) rotate(0deg); } /* Safari needs a 'from' */
  to { transform: translate(100vw, 0) rotate(360deg); }
}
```

```html
<pre>click to toggle the animation on/off</pre>
<div id="box" class="transition"></div>
```

With your code that would give:

```js
$(window).scroll(function() {
  if (!scrollTimerId)
    $('body').addClass('scrolling')
      .removeClass('transition-font-variation');

  clearTimeout(scrollTimerId);
  scrollTimerId = setTimeout(function() {
    const val = getComputedStyle(document.body).getPropertyValue('font-variation-settings');
    document.body.style.setProperty( 'font-variation-settings', val );
    $('body').removeClass('scrolling');
    document.body.offsetWidth; // force reflow
    $('body').addClass('transition-font-variation');
    document.body.offsetWidth; // force reflow
    document.body.style.removeProperty( 'font-variation-settings' );
    scrollTimerId = undefined;
  }, 150);
});
```

```css
body {
    font-family: "AG GX", Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
    font-size: 2vw;
    line-height: 2vw;
    font-variation-settings: 'wght' 1;
    height: 300vh;
}
body.transition-font-variation {
  transition: font-variation-settings 2s;
}
```

(type `$(window).off('scroll')` in your js console before applying these changes if you wish to try it from OP's website).

Comment: Thanks @Kaiido You're answer is exactly what I was hoping for. It works in Chrome, however in Safari it still snaps back to the beginning instead of finishing the rotation smoothly. Any ideas here? If this is working on Safari too then i'm happy to mark your answer as correct. I've put your code here to check live: http://slug.directory/GX1/

Comment: @R-J you are right, I didn't tested in Safari, and they act very weirdly wrt to transitions and animations (not far from being completely broken on their end). Anyway, I added a fix for Safari.

Comment: Bingo! nailed it! working well in Safari now too. thank you! Bounty is yours :-) + could you also explain what you mean by: '(type $(window).off('scroll')' in your js console before applying these changes if you wish to try it from OP's website).

Comment: It's meant for readers that want to apply it on your web-site from their browser's dev-tools. They have to remove your own handler before applying this new one.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't access your font, so I've used css property `color` instead!

To keep track of animation end-point, I've used [`animationiteration`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/animationiteration_event) event on body. The logic is,

> *If the animation completes "odd number of cycles", then change the `color` and `animation-direction`, and if it doesn't then, **do nothing**.*

Here's what I've added,

```
$('body').on('animationiteration', function() {
  if(started) {
    $('body').removeClass('scrolling');
    scrollTimerId = undefined;

    var cycles = Math.round((Date.now() - now) / 1000);
    if(cycles % 2) {
      if(currColor == 'rgb(0, 128, 0)') {
        currColor = 'rgb(255, 0, 0)';
        animDir = 'alternate-reverse';
      } else {
        currColor = 'rgb(0, 128, 0)';
        animDir = 'alternate';
      }
    }

    started = false;
    $('body').css('color', currColor);
    console.log(currColor, animDir, cycles);
  }
});
```

Further, I've used `started` in order to check if animation has started or not, and accordingly set property `animation-direction` **only once**.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  var scrollTimerId;
  var currColor = 'rgb(0, 128, 0)';
  var animDir = 'alternate';
  var started = false;
  var now;

  $('body').css('color', currColor);
  $(window).scroll(function() {
    if(!started) {
      if (!scrollTimerId)
        $('body').addClass('scrolling');

      $('.scrolling').css('animation-direction', animDir);
      started = true;
      now = Date.now();
    }
    
    clearTimeout(scrollTimerId);
    scrollTimerId = setTimeout(function() {
      $('body').on('animationiteration', function() {
        if(started) {
          $('body').removeClass('scrolling');
          scrollTimerId = undefined;
          
          var cycles = Math.round((Date.now() - now) / 1000);
          if(cycles % 2) {
            if(currColor == 'rgb(0, 128, 0)') {
              currColor = 'rgb(255, 0, 0)';
              animDir = 'alternate-reverse';
            } else {
              currColor = 'rgb(0, 128, 0)';
              animDir = 'alternate';
            }
          }

          started = false;
          $('body').css('color', currColor);
        }
      });
    }, 500);
  });

});
```

```css
@keyframes color {
  0% {
    color: green;
  }
  100% {
    color: red;
  }
}

.scrolling {
  animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-name: color;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-direction: alternate;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

body {
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
  font-size: 2vw;
  line-height: 2vw;
  height: 300vh;
}

div {
  position: fixed;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div>
  <p>To in ni test ommos ratiam, nihitat istinctatum voluptatio bea ipsantur sum quod magnatusant modi conse doloria di quosam necatatiost pro voluptam quae doluptasi. To in ni test ommos ratiam, nihitat istinctatum voluptatio bea ipsantur sum quod magnatusant
    modi conse doloria di quosam necatatiost pro voluptam quae doluptasi.</p>

  <p>To in ni test ommos ratiam, nihitat istinctatum voluptatio bea ipsantur sum quod magnatusant modi conse doloria di quosam necatatiost pro voluptam quae doluptasi sinctot amenimodia quam, cones is et aut la voloria non rehentus eium, volorit parum re,
    volorei cipidust, ut es doluptaquae coratum quide moluptaquis aut latiorrum adipitat lab ipsapicienim qui nusciun tioribus ea voluptam sim dolo experfe reratusae velitature pa pos ut et que simporrum ut ilitam, incto iunt et hitam natis net vellignimod
    magnis eum re odipiti ssequib earuptatia anto mi, qui derera dipsa volorendis volum es qui consequis acernam rem consequi aut eaquiatia destemo luptur, sae volo berumqui apicia sum que mo moluptium remoluptat qui sumque nonserro officiet ditiae int
    et elibus idellabore volor serum volent.</p>

  <p>To in ni test ommos ratiam, nihitat istinctatum voluptatio bea ipsantur sum quod magnatusant modi conse doloria di quosam necatatiost pro voluptam quae doluptasi sinctot amenimodia quam, cones is et aut la voloria non rehentus eium, volorit parum re,
    volorei cipidust, ut es doluptaquae coratum quide moluptaquis aut latiorrum adipitat lab ipsapicienim qui nusciun tioribus ea voluptam sim dolo experfe reratusae velitature pa pos ut et que simporrum ut ilitam, incto iunt et hitam natis net vellignimod
    magnis eum re odipiti ssequib earuptatia anto mi, qui derera dipsa volorendis volum es qui consequis acernam rem consequi aut eaquiatia destemo luptur, sae volo berumqui apicia sum que mo moluptium remoluptat qui sumque nonserro officiet ditiae int
    et elibus idellabore volor serum volent.</p>



</div>
```

[Try it live!](https://cdpn.io/Rahul_V7/debug/dyYXYGj/yPAJjKpWvdDA) (check out the console for more details)

---

You might be wondering why I didn't used [`animationend`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/animationend_event) directly on `body`. It is due to the fact that your animation is looping infinitely ;)

Comment: @R-J: I've removed `lastScroll` to make it bit simple. Any feedback?

Comment: I like your thinking here, however I don't think it works in practice. I've put your answer live here to check: http://slug.directory/GX3/  Did I implement it correctly, as it's not spinning anymore? thanks

Comment: @R-J: I can't debug the script on the website (I tried console logs, but it didn't worked). So, would you like to share your font so that I can debug it locally? It would be helpful.

Comment: Sure, the font is there already if you look in the you (c) know (s) what (s). Looking forward to the result :-) thanks!

Comment: @R-J: I didn't understood your first sentence's end. I was saying that you'd given a relative path to your font `url('../fonts/AccidenzTestGX.ttf')`, and hence I can never access your font. How do you say that it is there already?

Answer (score 0):

This should do it.

***CSS:***

```
@font-face {
    font-family: "AG GX";
    src: url('../fonts/AccidenzTestGX.ttf') format('truetype');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}

@keyframes changewidth {
  from, to {
    font-variation-settings: 'wght' 1;
  }

  50% {
    font-variation-settings: 'wght' 100;
  }
}

.scrolling {
  animation-duration: 0.5s;
  animation-name: changewidth;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}

body {
    font-family: "AG GX", Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
    font-size: 2vw;
    line-height: 2vw;
    height: 300vh;
    font-variation-settings: 'wght' 1;
    transition: font-variation-settings 0.5s;
}

div {
  position: fixed;
  }
}
```

I slightly changed the animation and removed `animation-direction: alternate;` as well as `animation-fill-mode: forwards;`. Just so you know.

***JS:***

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(window).scroll(function() {
    $('body').addClass('scrolling');
    clearTimeout($.data(this, 'scrollTimer'));
    $.data(this, 'scrollTimer', setTimeout(function() {
      var computedStyle = $('body').css('font-variation-settings');
      $('body').removeClass('scrolling');
      $('body').css('font-variation-settings', computedStyle);
      setTimeout(function() {
        $('body').css('font-variation-settings', "'wght' 1");
      }, 500);
    }));
  });
});
```

***JS Explanation:***

**Step 1:** Add `scrolling` class when scrolling.

**Step 2:** Add a `setTimeout` so we can activate an event when the user stops scrolling. (I saw you already had something of the sort, that's great).

**Step 3:** When user stops scrolling, get current `font-variation-settings` and store them as a variable (`computedStyle`).

**Step 4:** Remove `scrolling` class and set `font-variation-settings` to `computedStyle`.

**Step 5:** Wait 500ms so the transition can commence. After `.5s`, we reset `font-
variation-settings`.

---

Example on [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/barhatsor/x7rhousc/30) with `transform: rotate()`.

**Source:** This [CSS-Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/controlling-css-animations-transitions-javascript/) article and this [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9144560/jquery-scroll-detect-when-user-stops-scrolling) question.

Comment: Hi all, many thanks for your contributions–more than I expected. I'm looking into each thoroughly to test which works best for the site. More soon, thank you!

Comment: thanks for the answer, however it still snaps back to the position. Any thoughts? I've put your version here if you want to check what I mean: http://slug.directory/GX2/