# How can I make this jQuery listener not fire multiple times?

Tags: jquery, ajax, infinite-scroll

I currently have the following function which effectively retrieves JSON from Django and loads movies via infinite scroll.  However, I find that sometimes this event triggers multiple times, and it ends up getting the same page twice.

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
  var break_point = $(document).height() - ($(window).height() * 1.02);
  if ($(window).scrollTop() >= break_point) {
    var timePeriod = $('.tab-content').find('.active').attr('id');
    var nextPage = $('#'+timePeriod+' ul li:last').attr('data-next');
    if (nextPage) {
      loadMovies(timePeriod, nextPage);
    }
  }
});
```

What's the best way to stop this listener from executing multiple times per page?

Comment: [Is this what you're looking for?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9144560/jquery-scroll-detect-when-user-stops-scrolling) - Also related: [4620906](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4620906), [8931605](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8931605)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Rob for the help!  I'm just posting what I ended up doing for everyone else's reference.  I used the underscore.js library's debounce function.

```
var infiniteScroll = _.debounce(function() {
  var break_point = $(document).height() - ($(window).height() * 1.02);
  if ($(window).scrollTop() >= break_point) {
    var timePeriod = $('.tab-content').find('.active').attr('id');
    var nextPage = $('#'+timePeriod+' ul li:last').attr('data-next');
    if (nextPage) {
      loadMovies(timePeriod, nextPage);
    }
  }
}, 250);

$(window).scroll(infiniteScroll);
```

Answer (score 0):

use .one('scroll', function() instead of .scroll(function()

http://api.jquery.com/one/

Thinking about your functionality, you might have to reattach the handler on reload, though. But one() will ensure it only fires once after you attach it.

Comment: Hey, how would I reattach the handler after it fires?

Comment: You could, for example, put the code with one() into a function, and then call that function in your document ready and then call it again on return. Or, you could (same functionality) leave it as is, put it in a function, but the first time you make an ajax (presumably?) call, call unbind, and then call the function again on success.