# display parent horizontal scroll bar and child vertical scroll bar

Tags: html, css

I have a custom timeline view like this: http://jsfiddle.net/B4xRb/1/

The inner vertical scroll affects the rows beneath the header only.
The parent horizontal scroll affects the entire timeline.

```
<div class="parentDiv">
    <div class="monthHeader"></div>
    <div class="lanes"></div>
</div>
```

However, how could I structure this so that the vertical scroll bar can be seen WITHOUT

- adjusting the row data as it can be really wide.
- initially scrolling to the right, I want it so as you load the page, both scroll bars are visible

Comment: Seems to be working as you described on all browsers for me... the vertical scroll bar is on the right of the page regardless of page width and size of data. Well, if the width of the row data is too small, the scroll bar moves inward to the left... you can fix this by applying `width: 100%` to `.lanes`.

Comment: Then that causes other scroll bars to appear, try it out...

Comment: You're right, I didn't notice that at small sizes it does cause another horizontal scroll bar. Add `overflow-x: hidden;` to `.lanes` also. This is the fiddle I'm working on: http://jsfiddle.net/eB8WQ/

Comment: Also to prevent the vertical scroll bar.. `html, body { overflow-y: hidden; }` http://jsfiddle.net/eB8WQ/1/

Comment: Now if you scroll right, you see the vertical scroll in the middle of it all.

Comment: That's how it worked originally and wasn't listed as a problem in your initial post. If you want to use javascript to resize the window as you scroll, try this: http://jsfiddle.net/eB8WQ/5/. Because the animation looks "jittery", you might consider adding some logic to make the scroll bar disappear while the user is scrolling horizontally, then waits a second for the user to stop scrolling, then resizes the window allowing the scroll bar to reappear. Without using javascript, you might want to look into using frames or something of that sort.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the solution I came up with, using jQuery: http://jsfiddle.net/eB8WQ/6/

First off, to hide the second outside vertical scroll bar, add this code

```
html, body {
    overflow-y: hidden;
}
```

for `.lanes`, you want to hide the horizontal scroll bar and set the initial `width` to 100%.

```
width: 100%;
overflow-x: hidden;
```

Next, the javascript you want to use sets the width of `.lanes` to 100% while scrolling (to avoid the messy flickering problem), and when you're done scrolling, it calculates the position of the horizontal scrollbar and adds that value to the width of your `body` element. Use the `$.data` function to store the value.

More information on `$.data`: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/

```
$('.parentDiv').scroll(function() {
        $('.lanes').css("width", $('.monthHeader').width());
});
$('.parentDiv').scroll(function() {
    clearTimeout($.data(this, 'scrollTimer'));
    $.data(this, 'scrollTimer', setTimeout(function() {
        $('.lanes').css("width", $('.parentDiv').scrollLeft() + $('body').width() + "px");
    }, 100));
});
```

Some code taken from [this previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14035083/jquery-bind-event-on-scroll-stops).