# Peform a function if an element is completely in the viewport (live)

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I've tried to use a jQuery plugin [within viewport](https://github.com/cpatik/within-viewport)  to detect whether or not an element is in the viewport.

It works, but it doesn't update.

He recommandes [ScrollStop](http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/special-scroll-events-for-jquery/). I add it, but it doesn't work.

I only put my code here:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(window).bind("resize scrollStop", function() {
$("div").withinViewport().append("<span>hi</span>");
});
});
```

(plus, it's using the bind method, so it's a bit outdated..)

So, it may be simple, but I didn't get it to work.

I'm new to jQuery and javascript so.. It may be super simple.

[Here's the website with the code and everything](http://aurelieremia.be/tfa/about.html)

edit: works on resize ! but not on scroll.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From here

[jQuery - bind event on Scroll Stop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14035083/jquery-bind-event-on-scroll-stops)

```
$.fn.scrollStopped = function(callback) {           
        $(this).scroll(function(){
            var self = this, $this = $(self);
            if ($this.data('scrollTimeout')) {
              clearTimeout($this.data('scrollTimeout'));
            }
            $this.data('scrollTimeout', setTimeout(callback,250,self));
        });
    };

$(window).scrollStopped(function(){
    $("div").withinViewport().append("<span>hi</span>");
});
```

How this works.

The function is first clearing any timeout associated with the data element `scrollTimeout`.

It think creates a new element there with a timeout of 250 ms with the function passed in.

Thus while scroll is moving it is always clearing the function from running and resetting it to run "in a little bit".

When the scrolling stops -- then it can't clear the function so the function executes.

Cute trick.

Comment: Not sure to understand how it works completely. I'm going to work on that deeper later but I tested it and it works, so thank you ! Totally saved me from hours of code and nonsense. Thank you.

Comment: The current code has one downside though: You can't bind multiple times to one element with it. I edited the code for myself to accomplish this. Look at this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/e71cugvx/1/). :)

Comment: @Dennis98 -- I don't know -- using a global integer seems a little sketchy -- I'd implement an event list if you really need multiples.

Comment: @Hogan Good to know that this is possible. :D Would be nice, I currently don't need that, but there's a good chance that I want to bind multiple events to the window object later on, so having the possibility is appreciated.. :)

Comment: @Dennis98 -- using a list for events is a leading design -- you can look to the event model in C# and jQuery for examples.