# Javascript stop animation when scrolling stops

Tags: javascript, html, animation, scroll

I'm trying to have an animation play whilst the user is scrolling and stop when they stop.
I know very little javascript, but from hunting around and adapting I've got as far as making it start on scrolling, but then it keeps going and I can't figure out how to make it stop as soon as the scrolling ends.

Here's what I have so far:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    $('#square').animate({
        top: '70px',
        queue: true,
    }, 900).animate({
        top: '5px',
        queue: true
    }, 1000);
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/25s4txxd/5)

Any help greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a timer as follows:

var timer;

```
$(window).scroll(function() {

    clearTimeout(timer);
    timer = setTimeout( refresh , 150 );

    $('#square').animate({
        top: '70px',
        queue: true,
    }, 900).animate({
        top: '5px',
        queue: true
    }, 1000);

});

var refresh = function () { 
// do stuff
    $('#square').stop().clearQueue();
};
```

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/vggzrwr2/)**

Reference: [[Event when user stops scrolling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3701311/jquery-event-when-user-stops-scrolling)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3701311/jquery-event-when-user-stops-scrolling)

Comment: Thanks! That's pretty much what I was after.

Answer (score 1):

Updated your **[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/25s4txxd/8/)** using reference from another [Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14035083/jquery-bind-event-on-scroll-stop).

This will display to you when there is a `scroll` event occurring and when the `scroll` event stops.

The core of what you want is `$('#square').stop().clearQueue();` though.

Answer (score 0):

I've accomplished this with underscore's debounce and jquery:

https://github.com/michaelBenin/node-startup/blob/master/client/js/core/scroll_manager.js

To stop the animation see: http://api.jquery.com/stop/

Also see this library for animations: 
http://julian.com/research/velocity/