# Stop cursor from changing on a cursor div when the user scrolling the document jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Today I found out that Google+ set the cursor to initial when the user is scrolling, and the cursor won't change when hovering on all the hyperlinks or images while the user is still scrolling

How can I stop cursor from changing when the user is scrolling through divs with css attribute set to pointer. I have noticed that if the cursor keep changing when the user is scrolling, the scroll is not as smooth as when the cursor is unchanged. I have tried

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
        console.log('scrolling');
        $('body').css("cursor", "initial");

    });
```

but it seems it doesn't work, and other children's css attribute has overwritten the line, I didn't found any similar questions on Stack overflow, can someone point me to the right direction?

Comment: Not exactly sure what you are asking here, but maybe `pointer-events` can help you achieve what you want? http://www.thecssninja.com/css/pointer-events-60fps

Comment: let's say a div becomes cursor when is hovered, but when the user is scrolling the scroll bar, I want to keep the cursor unchanged even the user's cursor is hovering that div

Comment: Check the link that I posted.

Comment: @CBroe, I will check it out, looks promising

Comment: @CBroe,  thanks, I have figured out the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to link provided by CBroe, [disable cursor event when scrolling](http://%20thecssninja.com/css/pointer-events-60fps)  I have found that what I need is  to add `pointer-events: none;` to the body when the user is scrolling and remove it when the user stop scrolling.

**first** we need to add a class called disable-hover to our css file

```
.disable-hover {
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

**second**  we need to detect whether the user is scrolling and add or remove the class correspondingly

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
        $('body').addClass('disable-hover');

    });


    $(window).scrollStopped(function(){
        $('body').removeClass('disable-hover');
    });
```

that's it!

`scrollStoppped` plugin is contributed by Jason to detect the scrolling has stopped

[detect scroll stop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14035083/jquery-bind-event-on-scroll-stop/14035162#14035162)