# Add a class during Scroll

Tags: jquery, html, scroll

Is there a way to execute a function (ie Add Class, Remove Class...) **only during the time of Scrolling** a Specific div.

> For example
>
> If i'm having a div with a height of 1000px and overflow: auto
>   properties. I like to add a class on the time of scrolling only. If
>   the user stops scrolling inside a div that class has to be removed.

Is there any way of writing jquery to this function...

Answer (score 2):

Yeah pretty much everything can be put inside `.scroll()` event handler from jQuery.

http://api.jquery.com/scroll/

And to detect stop check out this post :

[Fire event after scrollling scrollbars or mousewheel with javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8931605/fire-event-after-scrollling-scrollbars-or-mousewheel-javascript)

You basically set a Timeout to check if you are still scrolling and if not trigger the stopped scrolling event

**EDIT: was funny to implement**

```
var scrollChecker = null;
var scrollTimeout = null;

var createScrollEvents = function (e) {
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.data('scrolling', true);
    if (!scrollChecker) {
        $this.trigger('scrollStart');
        scrollChecker = setInterval(function () {
            if (!$this.data('scrolling')) {
                $this.trigger('scrollStop');
                clearTimeout(scrollChecker);
                scrollChecker = null;
            }
        }, 200);
    }
    $this.trigger('scrolling');
    if (scrollTimeout) {
        clearTimeout(scrollTimeout);
    }
    scrollTimeout = setTimeout(function () {
        $this.data('scrolling', false);
    }, 200);
};

$(function () {

    $('#mydiv')

        //init
        .scroll(createScrollEvents)

        //events
        .on('scrollStart', function (e) {
            console.log('start');
        })

        .on('scrollStop', function (e) {
            console.log('stop');
        })

        .on('scrolling', function (e) {
            console.log('scrolling');
        });
        //end
});
```

**CSS**

```
#mydiv {
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
    overflow : auto;
}
```

don't forget this, read `.scroll()` documentation :

> It applies to window objects, but also to scrollable frames and
>   elements with the `overflow` CSS property set to `scroll` (or `auto` when
>   the element's explicit height or width is less than the height or
>   width of its contents).

http://jsfiddle.net/techunter/LxTqY/

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#target').scroll(function() {
$('.ClassName').removeClass(ClassName);
$(this).addClass(ClassName);
});
```

Comment: @ManjunathHedge not at all..... with $('*') you will retrieve the whole DOM which is reallyyyyyyyyy time consuming

Comment: I think this will only work at Start of the scroll.... But after stoping scroll i have to trigger another function...

Comment: @Jhonny: Use Timer.. refet this post
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9144560/jquery-scroll-detect-when-user-stops-scrolling

$(window).scroll(function() {
    clearTimeout($.data(this, 'scrollTimer'));
    $.data(this, 'scrollTimer', setTimeout(function() {
        // do something
        console.log("Haven't scrolled in 250ms!");
    }, 250));
});

Answer (score 0):

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/WrHN3/1/)**

you can use Jquery `.scroll()` but `overflow` CSS property set to `scroll` (or `auto` when the element's explicit height or width is less than the height or width of its contents).

Or

You can use `window.onscroll` event

Comment: window.onscroll event will not work bcoz i need scroll inside the div

Comment: so you need to use jquery scroll event but overflow CSS property set to scroll (or auto when the element's explicit height or width is less than the height or width of its contents).

Comment: Yeah but scroll only trigger event on starting the scroll but here i need some function on stoping the scroll function....